# How to list names of files in all directories and subdirectories in txt file in C?

Tags: c, file, directory, subdirectory

I would like to list all PDF files (CAD drawings) placed in directories and subdirectories corresponding with place in 3D model assembly also retaining information about level of each subdirectory. Drawing tree looks something like this ("[A]" states for assembly drawing"  - level is the same as that of parent directory):

```
DIR100
  DIR101
  DIR102
    [A]DRW102
    DRW1021
    DRW1022
    ...
  DIR103
    [A]DRW103
    DRW1031
    DRW1032
    ...
  ...
  [A]DRW100
  DRW1001
  DRW1002
```

So after executing a program, txt file should look like this:

```
LVL1 DIR100
  LVL2 DIR101
  LVL2 DIR102
    LVL2 [A]DRW102
    LVL3 DRW1021
LVL3 DRW1022
    ...
```

This is the first step for the project. As soon as I have list of files, I am able to automatically rename them.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel here. Why not try using an existing utility like `find`? For example, `find . -name "*.pdf" -print` should give you a hierarchical list of all the PDF files in the current directory and its subdirectories. This could be piped to a C program, or run from within C via a system call.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I also have Cygwin terminal

Comment: @user3386109 Windows ...I have tried `find` command, but no option `-print` there

Comment: I think squeamish was assuming linux. On windows, I've used the `_findfirst` `_findnext` and `_findclose` functions to scan directories.

Comment: From the command line you can use attrib *.pdf /s >list.txt to generate a text file. For a program do to this you may want to implement a recursive function with two loops. The first loop handles all the files, the second loop handles all the directories using recursion. This method groups all the files that belong to a directory together in a listing, before dealing with any sub-directories in a directory. This sequence is commonly used by backup programs.

Comment: @rcgldr `attrib` served me well. Thanks